# How to deal with voltage sag from a motor starting

Tags: dc-motor, buck, voltage

I have a buck converter LM2956, same as
 [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076H3XHXP)

stepping down voltage from 12 to 8 volts. A motor turns on from the regulated stepped down voltage, and when it does I get a voltage sag that drops the voltage down 1.5 volts (so from 8 to 6.5). it lasts for about 2 milliseconds which is unacceptable for my application.
How can I deal with this voltage sag? I have no passive components from the regulated 8volts to the motor driver.
attached is an oscilloscope image of the sag when starting the motor from the regulated voltage(goes from 5.4 v to 4v for 2 milliseconds in the image). This is messing with sensor readings a microcontroller reads by ADC. How would I go about solving this voltage sag problem.

more info:
the motor I use 
on load current < 1A
stall current 2.2 A

the lm2956
max current 3A

[image: image of voltage drag]

Comment: _"I get a voltage sag that drops the voltage down 1.5 volts... This is messing with sensor readings a microcontroller reads by ADC."_ - how can voltage sag at the _motor_ affect sensor readings in the MCU? Are you running the MCU off the same 8V supply?

Comment: why does your 12V supply do when the motor is turned on? does it fluctuate?

Comment: How is the motor connected to the regulator (lm2956) output? A transistor? Relay? Motor driver integrated circuit?

Comment: If a 1.5V drop on your 8V supply gives a 1.4V drop on your regulated 5.4V supply, you don't have a regulated 5.4V supply. What's generating that? Hopefully not a 7805 fed from 8V.

Comment: @Jasen The 12 volt unregulated also sags same as the regulated.

Comment: @jms the motor is connected to a motor driver L298n . the driver is connected to the regulated voltage along with sensors and microcontroller. at first I thought the input voltage was sagging below the what the regulated voltage was so I lowered the voltage much further to 5v regulated but I still got the same sag.

Comment: @BrianDrummond That is what I had been confused about as well. It seems the lm2956 is just not regulating it. I even added another lm2956. so it was  12v supply -> 8v regulated with motor attached -> 5v regulated with sensors. and still for every voltage I got the same voltage sag. Is not the point of the lm2956 to not have that happen.

Comment: Run the second 2596 from the 12V supply so it doesn't see the dropout.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I tried this and though the sag was not as much (1v drop this time), it still voltage sagged

Comment: If you have nearly the same sag on every supply, regardless of regulators, you probably have the wrong 0V reference point. Time to read about star earthing and how to keep high currents out of sensitive grounds.

Comment: @BrianDrummond So I have done something that takes most of the sag away but I dont understand exactly why it works. Before I had the input of the 2nd 2596 from the 12v, outputted to points on a breadboard rail. the 1st 2596 that goes to the motor is on the SAME breadboard but on the other rail of the breadboard. my oscilloscope is also connected to that rail the 2nd 2596 is. when i move the output  of the 2nd 2596 to a different breadboard along with the scope, I get a much lower sag of 0.1V that lasts 1 milli. Does this have to do with not star earthing or a quirk with breadboards?

Comment: wait what ... BREADBOARD? No wonder. Yes it has everything to do with power routing, poor earthing, oscilloscope signal probing, and breadboards. But you have seen an improvement so that is a start.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Yes, I assumed that because I was on different rails of the same breadboard, that the two voltages would not interfere with each other. I will continue to work on it until I get exactly the behavior I am looking for making sure to completely separate all regulated voltages to completely different  boards. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you are not supposed to have analog(motor) and digital(microcontroller) components on the same power rail as such noise affects the operation of digital circuits. The voltage drop is seen because, momentarily, the motor draws more current than the regulator can supply, and hence this results in a voltage drop. After the motor starts rotating, the current required is lower due to the back EMF of the motor and hence the voltage is stable. 
Consider adding a capacitor across the VCC and GND of the 8V and 12V. You can start with a 1uF capacitor. This will reduce the momentary drop. If it is not enough, you can try a higher capacitance.

Comment: I tried the capacitor in parallel but saw no difference. Started with a 1uf and worked up to the highest I have 220uf. I'm not sure there was any difference. I tried moving the sensor to a second layer of 5v regulated voltage from the 8v regulated and even still there was the same sag despite the 8v sag not going lower then 5v at any time.

Comment: Did you place the cap across VCC and GND? If it is an electrolytic cap, check polarity. Do not add it at the motor terminals as there is no voltage initially to charge it. If you are seeing no difference with and without capacitor, there is something wrong. 
If nothing works, Use a separate battery for the power input of the motor driver. Make sure you connect the GND of both the batteries. In this config, the 1st battery supplies to micro controller and 2nd for motor.

Answer (score 1):

Typically - to avoid that current spike - you would soft start the motor by increasing the voltage supplied to it over a longer period of time (instead of abruptly dumping 8 V to it). In practice this is usually accomplished with pulse-width modulation (PWM).

You could also bypass the regulated 8 V supply and drive that motor straight from the 12 V supply. If you use a PWM driver and keep the duty cycle at 66%, your motor will still effectively receive 8 volts although powered from a 12 V supply. This way the motor won't bog down the the 8 V supply while stalled. Perhaps more importantly, that would greatly reduce the presence of electrical noise from the motor on the 8 V supply. A noisy power supply will easily ruin any analog signals (like sensor readings) and when severe enough could crash the microcontroller.